# In ActiveAdmin Select from list of polymorphic items

Tags: activeadmin, polymorphic-associations

So I have a list of items you can select multiple from and the list is of to different things (polymorphic) but I'm not sure how to implement this as what I have isn't working.

I've looked but I can't seem to find anything on this, only on how to filter polymorphic associations (not useful at this juncture).

Currently what I have:

```
  f.input :items,  multiple: true, as: :select, collection: Section.top_level.all + NavigationItem.all
```

I'd also like to add that I have found stuff on polymorphic nested form stuff but again, not relevent to what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use select2 for AA ?

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
        f.input :sections, as: :select2_multiple, :collection => NavigationItem.find_by_sql('select * from navigation_items'}).pluck(:name, :id)
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

You can use find_by_sql to search through all polymorphic model across main table. Of course you will want to modify the query to use correct models and section levels.